# Pullback of the Frobenius map and function fields extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, extension-field, algebraic-curves

We know that for two nonsingular projective algebraic curves defined over a field $\mathbf{k}$, there is a bijection between nonconstant morphisms $h: C \to C'$ and function fields injections $h^* : \mathbf{k}(C') \to \mathbf{k}(C)$, where $h^*G = G \circ h$.
Also, if $C$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$, the Frobenius map on $C$ is 
$$ \sigma_p : C \to C^{\sigma_p}, \quad [x_0:\dots:x_n] \mapsto [x_0^p:\dots:x_n^p]. $$

Now, the example I'm looking at is $C = \mathbf{P}^1(\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p)$, with $\sigma_p(t) = t^p$ on the affine part. Diamond and Shurman say that this gives the extension of function fields $\mathbf{F}_p(t)/\mathbf{F}_p(s)$, where $s = t^p$ and this is what I don't understand. Why is the function field $\mathbf{K}$ of $C$ not $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p(t)$, and how does one get $\mathbf{F}_p(s)$ for the function field of $C^{\sigma_p}$? Do we need to compute the function field explicitly or the preimage of the pullback map $\sigma_p^*$ instead? I would guess the second but it's not very clear to me how this is done exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I understand your confusion and I hope this answer can clear it up. However, it is somewhat of a fine point and if I fail, please point that out.

You have a morphism $\sigma_p: \Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb P^1$. Let us denote the function field of the *right* side by $\overline{\Bbb F}_p(t)$ and the function field of the one on the *left* side (domain of $\sigma_p$) by $\overline{\Bbb F}_p(s)$. They are in fact the **same** field when considered independently, i.e. $s$ and $t$ play the same role for each of them respectively. However, the different variables will help us keep track of what is happening when we see them *in relation* to one another.

Take the function $t\in\overline{\Bbb F}_p(t)$, a rational function on the image of $\sigma_p$. We then compute its image under the map $\sigma_p^\ast$, which is a function on the domain of $\sigma_p$:
$$
\sigma_p^\ast(t)=t\circ \sigma_p=s^p
$$
This is true because for any point $x\in\Bbb A^1\subseteq\Bbb P^1$, we have $t(\sigma_p(x))=t(x^p)=x^p=s(x)^p$. Now this means that the map $\sigma_p^\ast:\overline{\Bbb F}_p(t)\to\overline{\Bbb F}_p(s)$ which defines your field extension is given by mapping $t$ to $s^p$, because there only is one field homomorphism over $\overline{\Bbb F}_p$ that does so: This follows from the fact that there is only one $\overline{\Bbb F}_p$-algebra homomorphism $\overline{\Bbb F}_p[t]\to\overline{\Bbb F}_p(s)$ with $t\mapsto s^p$, the universal property of the polynomial ring.

So maybe a better way for you to understand this homomorphism is to accept $s$ as the "smallest" variable in all the universe and then define $t:=s^p$. Then, the next important realization is the fact that $\overline{\Bbb F}_p(t)$ is still a function field in one variable, even if it is *"just"* $\overline{\Bbb F}_p(s^p)$.

For a more concrete and different example, the fields $\Bbb Q(\pi)$ and $\Bbb Q(\pi^8)$ are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(t)$, where $t$ is a formal variable: That's because both $\pi$ and $\pi^8$ are transcendental. So is $t$, and so is $t^{23453}$. There are a lot of things that behave like an independent variable over $\Bbb Q$, or over $\overline{\Bbb F}_p$ for that matter.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand now, though you've exchanged the roles of $s$ and $t$. Your response also seems to imply that the function fields is $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ and not $\mathbb{F}_p$, can you confirm this?

Comment: I completely missed that bit about the missing algebraic closure! But yes, if your curve is the projective line over the *closure* of $\Bbb F_p$, then the function field will very much also be over the closure, not the prime field.